# Permutation Group-$S_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

How many elements of order $30$ are there in the symmetric group $S_{10}$?

I worked out and got $10500$ - using Computations and adjusting each individual cycle's position ( $2-3-5$ , $3-2-5$ etc). but then I realized that disjoint cycles commute. So got a little bit confused, Help? :)

Comment: Perhaps share how you worked out $5250$.

Comment: I'll just edit it , I got 10500 , I have explained in my comment to the answer posted below :) . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get an element of order $30$ in $S_{10}$ is as a disjoint product of a $2$-cycle, a $3$-cycle, and a $5$-cycle. So first we select the indices going into each category; the number of such choices is $$\frac{10!}{2! \cdot 3! \cdot 5!}.$$ Then we need to choose exactly what order to permute the indices for each cycle in. For the $2$-cycle, there is only one option. For the $3$-cycle, there are two choices. For the $5$-cycle, there are $4!$ choices (can you figure out why?). Multiply that out, and you should get a total of $120960$ elements of order $30$, if I did my math right.

Comment: Hmm,I took 6 cases(rotating the cycles of order 2,3,5 and evaluating like-10C2*8C3*5C5) and actually my answer came out to be 10500 not 5250( which is wrong via Lagrange's Theorem). I somehow don'd get your method :(.Thanks still!

Comment: That's the same value for the first part. I had a brainfart in the first edit, but it doesn't change the computation at all.

Comment: So $_{10} C_2*_8C_3*_5C_5$ should have been $2520$; is that what you got for that part? I don't understand what you did after that...

Comment: Still Confused , Maybe I'd try to right down your suggestion and test it by taking permutations out of it-Brain needs rest now :P. Thanks Again! :D

Comment: So the calculation I showed u in my comment is just one of them ( like another one is 10C5*5c2*3C3...Working like that :)

Comment: Oh. But like you said, disjoint cycles commute. So the order in which you select the cycles doesn't matter.

Comment: Thats what got me spiralling and made me question my approach - Somehow I cant grasp how you're putting-its either my lack of mathematical prowess or maybe we don't use the same expression, you know.Like-I lost my way after-"Then we need to choose exactly what order to permute the indices for each cycle in"(couldnt understand waht you meant there) :)

Comment: So we've selected indices to be grouped into a $2$-cycle, a $3$-cycle, and a $5$-cycle; say, to be concrete, that the grouping is $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4, 5\}, \{6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$. Now how do we select the cycles? For the $2$-cycle, it might appear that we have two choices, namely $(12)$ and $(21)$. But in fact $(12)=(21)$, so there's only one choice there. Then we continue to see how many distinct $3$-cycles can be made out of $3, 4, 5$, and how many $5$-cycles can be made out of $6, 7, 8, 9, 10$. Does that strategy make sense?

Comment: Yes!!! ( Eureka moment)-I guess rather than goin round and round I should have straight away asked you for an example-Its just I am pretty scared of people here at stack exchange(Just havent had friendly encounters :) ) Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: "10C2*8C3*5C5" looks like chemistry. ;)

Answer (score 0):

We want to determine the number of permutations in $S_{10}$ of order 30.  Since the order of a permutation is the least common multiple of the lengths of its cycles, and since 30 is $2 \times 3 \times 5$ or $5 \times 6$ (but a 5-cycle and 6-cycle require 11 points, whereas we are in $S_{10}$), we want to determine the number of permutations in $S_{10}$ consisting of a 2-cycle, a 3-cycle, and a 5-cycle.  Here are two ways to do this:

We need to fill in the blanks in $(-,-)(-,-,-)(-,-,-,-,-)$.  The points in the first 2-cycle can be chosen in ${10 \choose 2}$ ways.  The next 3-cycle can be chosen in ${8 \choose 3} \times (3-1)!$ ways since in general there are $(n-1)!$ different circular permutations of length $n$.  Finally, the 5-cycle can be chosen in $(5-1)!$ ways.  Multiplying these out, we get ${10 \choose 2} \times 2 \times {8 \choose 3} \times 2! \times 4! = 120960$.

Another way is as follows.  The 10 blanks can be filled in $10!$ ways.  Consider the  blanks in the 3-cycle: the three choices $(1,2,3)$ and two of its circular shifts $(2,3,1)$ and $(3,1,2)$ are actually the same permutation (i.e. the same bijective function). So we need to divide by $3$ for this reason.  Overall, we need to divide $10!$ by the length of each of the cycles, and we get $\frac{10!}{2 \times 3 \times 5}=120960$.